# Jquery.load URL from different folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url

How do I use `.load` if my file is in different folder?

I have tried:

```
$("#messageWindow").load("http://localhost/MainFolder/Messanging/index.php");   
$("#messageWindow").load("Messanging/index.php");   
$("#messageWindow").load("../Messanging/index.php");
```

nothing works, I have read topic about `different folders` when using URL but I can't seem to make their answers work.

Thanks.

Okay, I have Fixed the problem `The 1st and 2nd URL above WORKS` but I have another problem. The `index.php` have tons of URLs.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/timezone/jstz.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file_js/index.js"></script>
```

but now those URls are not working anymore, and the solution i took was to add the whole URL.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/MainFolder/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/MainFolder/plugins/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/MainFolder/plugins/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/MainFolder/plugins/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/MainFolder/plugins/timezone/jstz.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/MainFolder/Messanging/file_js/index.js"></script>
```

this is a hustle if I uploade the file to my web host. I think using relative pathing would do the trick but I don't know how that works.

Comment: What do you see in the `console` \ `firebug`?

Comment: I think you need to provide further details. First, does the url work in browser ("http://localhost/MainFolder/Messanging/index.php")? Second have you tried using for a url in the same folder? And one other thing: is "Messanging" spelled as the name of the folder? (sorry if the last one seems a bit stupid, but I have done lots of mistakes like that :D)

Comment: Yes, it's a misspelled folder.

Comment: @gdoron Console doesn't display anything.

Comment: When I use the 3rd line above, The console displays `GET http://localhost/Messanging/index.php 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @Mircea Yes, `("localhost/MainFolder/Messanging/index.php";)`. I tried that too and it works.

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) you can include the relative path from the current page or an absolute path. If you run the command below in the JS console or firebug you should see this same question twice in your browser.

```
$("#header").load("/questions/10643503/jquery-load-url-from-different-folder");
```

Content also needs to come from the same origin as the original page (*you can only load content from the same domain*).

Comment: we can use relative and absolute paths with the `load` method